# Problemas em executar aplicativo do android studio no celular

Tags: android, usb

[image: esta imagem e oque acontece quando eu clico em Run]estou tentando testar o aplicativo do android Studio no celelular e quando eu abro o emulator do android aparece essa frase em amarelo NO USB DEVICES, dai eu cliquei no troubleshoot e buscou os Scan e mesmo assim nao da certo oque eu posso fazer ?

Answer (score 1):

Opa, tudo bem!?

Verifique se a depuração USB no seu Android do seu celular está ativada. A depuração USB está destinada a conectar e compartilhar informações entre um smartphone e um computador.

> Como ativar a depuração

1. Abra as Configurações;
2. Selecione "Sobre o dispositivo";
3. Pressione 7 vezes Número de Compilação / Versão Build / Número da
   versão;
4. Volte para as Configurações;
5. Escolha Opções do Desenvolvedor e ative-a, bem como extras;
6. Habilite Depuração de USB.

O processo pode, obviamente, ser desfeito, simplesmente desativando a Depuração USB no seu dispositivo. Você também pode revogar qualquer a autorização de depuração USB dos computadores autorizados. Basta clicar em Revogar autorizações de depuração USB nas opções do desenvolvedor.

> Caso o problema persista dando erro de adb

Muitas vezes no Windows ele não reconhecerá o dispositivo completamente e, devido a problemas de driver, o dispositivo não será exibido.

1. vá para as configurações
2. Painel de controle
3. hardware e som
4. gerenciador de Dispositivos

E procure por qualquer dispositivo que mostre um erro. Muitos Android's serão exibidos como um dispositivo USB desconhecido. Selecione esse dispositivo e tente atualizar os drivers para ele.

> Outra possível solução

Certifique que a depuração USB está ativa. já notei um ícone no canto superior esquerdo que dizia: "Conectado como um dispositivo de mídia. Toque para outras opções de USB". Clique em cima dele e mude de MTP (Media Device, dispositivo de mídia) para PTP (Câmera) e, em seguida teste.